# How to access variable's value from base class in derived class?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

class Foo {
    protected: // Make x visible to derived classes
        int x;
    public: 
        Foo() {
           x = 2;
        }
};

class Derived : public Foo {
    public: 
        Derived() {
            x = 4;
        }

        void print(){
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
};


int main() {
    Derived a;
    a.print();
}
```

This prints 4.I want to access both the values of x in print.I want to print 2 and 4 both.Do I need to creat object of Foo in Derived class and access it through object.x?But that calls the constructor of Foo more than once.I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Use a separate member variable for the `Derived` class?

Comment: A variable only has one value at a time.

Comment: *"I want to print 2 and 4 both"* - `std::cout << 2 << 4 << '\n'`? Seriously, what do you mean?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I think it should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only *one* `x` in the object total. Not one in the `Foo` part and one in the `Derived` part. So when your Derived constructor assigns 4 to `x` then that is the value of the variable, period.
If you need to hold two distinct values then you need two variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need two variables to hold two values.